# Dependências do NetFramework na pasta do projeto?

Tags: .net, vb.net, framework

Gostaria de saber se é possível embutir, de alguma maneira, as `.dll` que o meu projeto usa do NetFramework em sua própria pasta. Dessa forma não seria necessário a instalação do NetFramework no computador do cliente, visto que todas as dependências se encontrariam na pasta do programa.

Percebi que a grande maioria dos softwares de grande marca utilizam desse artifício, só não sei ainda como realizá-lo.

Obs: Utilizo a versão 13 do Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Isto é uma funcionalidade fresquinha (na data desta resposta). Será inclusa no Visual Studio 2015 e se chama [Microsoft .NET Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx).

Se for anterior ao Framework 4.5.2, não tem como. Tem que instalar o Framework mesmo.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela resposta Cigano!
Só que eu já fiz um projeto com a versão 2013, devo refazê-lo agora com a versão 2015 ou eu posso de algum jeito migrar o meu projeto sem causar danos ?

Comment: É possível a migração. Não sei como fazer.